# Difference between using _(obj).map(callback) and _.map(obj, callback) in underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, wrapper, lodash, chaining

Is there any difference in approach of invoking map method from the perspective of which data it will return?

I expect that when I do

```
_(object).map(callback);
```

it leads to creating new underscore class instance and returned value is an underscore's wrapper

rather than using

```
_.map(obj, callback)
```

utilizes the same (already created)  instance of underscore and returns plain JavaScript array as expected

Comment: `Is there any difference in approach of invoking map` - Functionality wise, no.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you don't ever plan on chaining any function calls after *or* before `map()`, then there's no point in wrapping the value. On the other hand, structuring chains that [applicatively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_programming_language) transform collections leads to compact and readable code.

Depending on the structure of your application, wrapper instances can be passed around from function to function, and built upon. This works because they're lazy in the sense that the chained calls aren't actually run till `value()` is called.

They're also lazy from an evaluation perspective. Here's a good resource on [lazy evaluation](http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/) in lodash.

Comment: Thank you, useful notes! The one important thing here, that lazy evaluation applicable for lodash only, as underscore currently does not support this.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, the result of the chained syntax is identical to the non-chained system.

Mostly, the chaining syntax is just a more readable syntax for performing several operations at once.

Most people find this chained syntax:

```
_(ds)
    .groupBy("group")
    .map(function(group) {
        return _.sample(group, n);
    })
    .flatten()
    .value();
```

Much more readable than a non-chained syntax:

```
_.flatten(_.map(_.groupBy(ds), "group", function(group) {
    return _.sample(group, n);
}))
```

But again, both will give you the same result.

---

However, in lodash, (as of version 3.0) there *is* a potential performance benefit to using the chaining syntax, as it uses lazy evaluation.  This means that it will defer as much evaluation as possible in order to minimize the operations needed to calculate the result, and also to reduce the number of temporary arrays created.

The article Adam Boduch linked on [lazy evaluation](http://filimanjaro.com/blog/2014/introducing-lazy-evaluation/) seems like a good resource, or you can read the [overview for Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/), which was essentially a lazy evaluation version of lodash/underscore before lodash supported lazy evaluation itself.  Though that one is out of date, in that it doesn't reflect that lazy evaluation has been added to lodash since the time it was written.

Underscore may eventually add lazy evaluation to their chaining syntax eventually but I haven't seen anything to indicate that that's on their roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation! My apologizes, probably I've bit confused you guys, question was about different thing. In fact, I came to this question while migrating from underscore to lodash on existing project. Lodash states that it fully compatible with underscore. But in practice, after switching to lodash constructions like _(obj).map(callback) work different, relative to underscore. Latter returns plain array, while lodash will return wrapper here.